# How do I sanitize invalid UTF-8 in Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8, sanitization

My Perl program takes some text from a disk file as input, wraps it in some XML, then outputs it to STDOUT. The input is nominally UTF-8, but sometimes has junk inserted. I need to sanitize the output such that no invalid UTF-8 octets are emitted, otherwise the downstream consumer (Sphinx) will blow up.

At the very least I would like to know *if* the data is invalid so I can avoid passing it on; ideally I could remove just the offending bytes. However, enabling all the fatalisms I can find doesn't quite get me there with perl 5.12 (FWIW, `use v5.12; use warnings qw( FATAL utf8 );` is in effect).

I'm specifically having trouble with the sequence `"\xFE\xBF\xBE"`. If I create a file containing only these three bytes (`perl -e 'print "\xEF\xBF\xBE"' > bad.txt`), trying to read the file with mode `:encoding(UTF-8)` errors out with `utf8 "\xFFFE" does not map to Unicode`, but only under 5.14.0. 5.12.3 and earlier are perfectly fine reading and later writing that sequence. I'm unsure where it's getting the `\xFFFE` (illegal reverse-BOM) from, but at least having a complaint is consistent with Sphinx.

Unfortunately, `decode_utf8("\xEF\xBF\xBE", 1)` causes no errors under 5.12 or 5.14. I'd prefer a detection method that didn't require an encoded I/O layer, as that will just leave me with an error message and no way to sanitize the raw octets.

I'm sure there are more sequences that I need to address, but just handling this one would be a start. So my questions are: can I reliably detect this kind of problem data with a perl before 5.14? What substitution routine can generally sanitize almost-UTF-8 into strict UTF-8?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should read the [UTF-8 vs. utf8 vs. UTF8 section](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode#UTF-8_vs._utf8_vs._UTF8) of the  [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) docs.

To summarize, Perl has two different UTF-8 encodings.  Its native encoding is called `utf8`, and basically allows any codepoint, regardless of what the Unicode standard says about that codepoint.

The other encoding is called `utf-8` (a.k.a. `utf-8-strict`).  This allows only codepoints that are listed as legal for interchange by the Unicode standard.

`"\xEF\xBF\xBE"`, when interpreted as UTF-8, decodes to the codepoint [U+FFFE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffe/index.htm).  But that's not legal for interchange according to Unicode, so programs that are strict about such things complain.

Instead of using `decode_utf8` (which uses the lax `utf8` encoding), use `decode` with the `utf-8` encoding.  And read the [Handling Malformed Data](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode#Handling_Malformed_Data) section to see the different ways you can handle or complain about problems.

Update: It does appear that some versions of Perl don't complain about U+FFFE, even when using the `utf-8-strict` encoding.  This appears to be a bug.  You may just have to build a list of codepoints that Sphinx complains about and filter them out manually (e.g. with [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr)).

Comment: Code examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735721/checklist-for-going-the-unicode-way-with-perl/3736787#3736787

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Since allowable Unicode characters in XML are well defined, `tr[\x{9}\x{A}\x{D}\x{20}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}][]cd` looks like it will work, at least in 5.14. An entirely different suggestion I found doesn't rely on a new perl at all: `iconv -c --from UTF-8 --to UTF-8`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a utf8 string containing some invalid utf8...

This replaces it with a default 'bad char'.

```
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my $octets    = decode('UTF-8', $malformed_utf8, Encode::FB_DEFAULT);

my $good_utf8 = encode('UTF-8', $octets,         Encode::FB_CROAK);
```