# Sanitizing a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading an excel(`.xlsx`) file (using module `Spreadsheet::XLSX`) and getting values like : `Iron/ Steel.Â`

**Problem**: The characters `Â` and  are not (visible) in the excel file. The rightmost character  looks like a white space but isn't as I tried the regex `/\s+$/` which didn't work.

Please help how I can clean this string. I want only those characters in my string which are on general English keyboards, i.e., `A-Z, 0-9, ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-` `  `,./';[]\|}{:"?><` etc.

Comment: Isn't it a problem of wrong [encoding](http://p3rl.org/Encode)?

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried the solution given here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509489. didn't work for me.

Comment: What does the cell actually contain in Excel?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking. I don't know who made these excels file or how s/he made these. Whether all data was typed in or copy/pasted. It only has some name like `Iron/ Steel`, `computers` and some numbers. I was facing this issue only for 3-4 cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all non ascii chars,

```
$string =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

When it's always the same position, I think a `substr($string, 0, -3)` can help!

Comment: Neat. But does not actually solve my problem. The characters that I've mentioned in the question are not in all of the strings, only some of them.