# Improper UTF-8 and LibXML::Reader

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

I have a large XML file from a remote source, that says it is 'UTF8', file shows us-ascii.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>...

file -bi <file> indicates application/xml; charset=us-ascii
Encode::Guess indicates UTF8
```

Edit: There is also some code which reads in the file, originally output from a LWP get...I have also try to force some encoding here, but get other errors like wide chars.

```
my $fh = IO::File->new;
$fh->open( '<' . $filename )
$content = join '', <$fh>;
```

I am using XML::Reader

```
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(string => $content) or die qq(cannot read content: $!);

while ($reader->nextElement($template->{ 'item' } )) {
    my $copy = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    my $test = $copy->findvalue( 'description' )
...# do other stuff with $copy
```

This works fine through most of the contents. However, there looks to be some invalid utf-8 or malformed data as it gives an error half way through..
(note, in XML::Bare the whole xml is processed 'fine' as its more forgiving, but the file is on the limit of memory size, so I need a smaller memory xml parser).

```
Entity: line 64070: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x1A 0x73 0x20 0x73
```

If I look in vim at the point after last success, I can see

```
^Z  or <^Z>  26,  Hex 1a,  Octal 032 with :ascii in vim
```

I have looked [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234386/how-do-i-sanitize-invalid-utf-8-in-perl) to try and ensure at least valid UTF-8 as I can't get the origin fixed, and trying...

```
use Encode qw( encode decode );
my $octets = decode('UTF-8', $content, Encode::FB_DEFAULT );
$content = encode('UTF-8', $octets, Encode::FB_CROAK );
```

But I still get the same error. I am happy to skip any parts with invalid UTF-8, but the whole parser dies, and I can't see any way to carry on processing later (which I believe is supposed to happen with XML parsing).

My question is, is this the best way to guarantee UTF-8 (assuming I can't get the file changed), or is there a method that should get around the error (I could probably regex that particular char out, but I'm assuming there may be other similar issues later, so feels clunky) ?

Comment: Normally I would expect code like `XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => "http://example.com/file.xml")`, then the XML parser will take care of parsing and decoding as needed. If you load from a string with `new(string => $content)`, where/how do you create that string when you get the error about improper UTF-8?

Comment: I have just added an edit near the top.

Comment: Tip: `open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn) or die $!;` would be better, as it ensures the file is "binary".

Comment: Tip: `XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => $fh)` would make far more sense than loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Thanks ikegami, there's a different process that loads the files in which is why it was that way, but I will look to see if we can change that slightly, as reducing memory would be valuable. I will also look at the loading in as binary. Very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading; the problem has nothing to do with encoding<sup>[1]</sup>. In fact, the error I receive is the following<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
:1: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 26
```

From the XML spec,

> ```
> Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

U+001A may not legally appear in XML files, not even as a character reference (`&#x1A;`).

> Characters referred to using character references `must` match the production for Char.

If the file is to contain binary data, the binary portions should be encoded (e.g. using base64).

---

1. `1A`, `20` and `73` are all less than `80`.
2. I tested using XML::LibXML rather than XML::LibXML::Reader, but I suspect the relevant difference is actually a difference in the version of XML::LibXML or libxml2.

Comment: Thank you, this has led me in the right direction now with looking at valid xml.