# How to test/classify CPAN modules for utf8 correctness

Tags: perl, utf-8, cpan

Here is an excellent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162484/632407) and the wonderful [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) with 7+24+52 advices&comments how to make an perl program utf8 safe.

But here is 19k CPAN modules. What is possible *to do* for differentiating "good" and "bad" ones? (from the utf8's point of view)

For example: `File::Slurp` if you will read the file with

```
#use strict encoding warnings utf8 autodie... etc....
my $str = read_file($file, binmode => ':utf8');
```

you will get different results based on command line switches, and `perl -CSDA` will not work. Sad. (Yes, i know than Encode::decode("utf8", read_file($file, binmode => ':raw')); will help, but *SAD* anyway.

**My questions:**

- is here any preferred way, how to test/classify what CPAN modules are utf8 safe/ready/correct?
- is here some Test::something already done for utf8 testing?
- is here something like Perl::Critic for utf8 - what will check the module source for possible utf8 incorrectness? (because manually checking sources for 7+24+52 things i cannot classify as the "easy way to programming")
- or any other way? :)

I understand, than much of CPAN modules simply does not need to know about utf8. But here are zilion others what should.

Please, don't misunderstand me. **I love Perl language**. I know than perl has extremely powerful utf8 capability. (especially 5.14). The above was not mean as perl critique - but me (and probably some others too) need to know what CPAN modules are OK, and how classify them...)

*When doing development using several CPAN modules, and initially everything goes well but in the final testing, you find that some modules does not support utf8, and therefore part of your work is useless - that really can cause a bit disillusionment. :(*

Edit:

I understand than all complicated things around the unicode has two roots:

1. unicode itself - as tchrist excellently analyzed some of problematic points
2. perl - simple can't break all working modules, live servers etc - so need maintaining backward compatibility.

My only hope: perl6. Is is an totally new and different language. Don't need maintaining any backward compatibility. So I hope, in perl6 will be **default** some things what is not possible do in perl5 and all utf8 things will be much more intuitive.

But, back to modules: @daxim told: *"Authors won't even reveal whether their module is taint-safe, and this feature exists for decades!"* - and this is a catastrophe. Maybe (big maybe, and honestly haven't idea how to do it), but maybe we arrived to the time, when need put much-much harder restrictions into CPAN submissions.

At one side i'm really very happy with volunteer works of CPAN authors. At the other side, publishing source code is not only like a free speech "right" - but should obey some rules too.

I understand, than is is nearly impossible make any "revolution", but we probably need some "evolution". Maybe flag any CPAN module what is not utf8 safe. Flag all what are not taint safe. Flag (like here in SO) what module does not meet the minimal coding standards and remove them. Maybe I'm an idealist and/or naive. :)

Comment: if you don't want to find out "in the final testing", then test early and test often! In the end, you have to test what's important for you, whether in your code or in a module. (interesting question though)

Comment: Yes, you're right. ;) But at the conceptual/projecting phase would be nice to know, what is possible to use and what not. Nice example in with Mason2. If do you decide than you will use Mason2 for the development, (for example together with Dancer), and you discover than it is has not supporting utf8 (regardless of Dancer's utf8 settings) - it is a bad and too late. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chill, the situation is less dire than you're thinking. No one except tchrist operates on this level of Unicode correctness, also see [Aristotle's recent commentary](http://blogs.perl.org/users/aristotle/2011/06/antiperlconfirmationbias.html). As with all things, you get 80% of the way with 20% of the effort. This base effort, namely [getting the topic of character encoding right](http://p3rl.org/unitut#SUMMARY), is well documented; and [jrockway repeats it in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162484#6192088) in that thread.

Replies to your specific questions:

1. No, there isn't. There is no concerted effort to collect this information in a central place. The Perl 5 wiki could be used to document problematic modules, Juerd already discusses some in [uniadvice](http://juerd.nl/site.plp/perluniadvice). I would really like to see a statement from each module author in their documentation that "this module DTRT w.r.t. encoding", but I don't see it happening. Authors won't even reveal whether their module is taint-safe, and this feature exists for decades!
2. [encoding::warnings](http://p3rl.org/encoding::warnings) can be used to smoke out unintended upgrades. I mention it in the work-flow of [Checklist for going the Unicode way with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3735721/#3736787)
3. You can't do that with Perl::Critic or static analysis. I see no other way than knowledgable people poking at the module with pointy characters until it falls apart (or not), like mirod just commented.

Comment: thanx. As i read your 1st link http://blogs.perl.org/users/aristotle/2011/06/antiperlconfirmationbias.html , now I think that my question comes in the wrong time. ;( Here are too much flames around. thanx for the links anyway.

Comment: it's often hard for authors to know how the module is going to perform when faced with inputs in various, often unknown, encodings.

Comment: Is `encoding::warnings` actually still needed given the `/dual` modifiers and the `unicode_strings` feature?  In Perl, bytes are just code points smaller than 256.

Comment: I have forwarded the question to the `perl-unicode@perl.org` list.

Comment: wow ;) I'm going to subscribe. I didn't know that there is such a list. Thanx for the info.