# Convert an iso-8859-1 symbol in a string to utf-8 in Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
my $str = '21156_MLA Ã Copy4.ens';
```

I'm using this `$str` in my code, and it should display as `21156_MLA ß Copy4.ens`.

I'm uploading a file with the filename `21156_MLA ß Copy4.ens`, but on the browser display it's displaying as `21156_MLA Ã Copy4.ens`. In the database it's stored properly as `ß`, but when we are retrieving that from the DB (using `fetchall_hashref`) it's getting converted to `Ã`. Subsequently the display on the browser is `21156_MLA Ã Copy4.ens`. How to avoid this conversion here?

Comment: 1. Replace the code in your question with the output of `use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper ); { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0; local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print('my $str = '.Dumper($str)."\n"); }`.

Comment: 2. Supply the values you pass to `DBI->connect`. (Feel free to replace the db,host,port,user,passwd with different words.)

Comment: 3. Add the charset do you specify (in the Content-Type) for the HTML you output (if any), and tell us how you encode the data you send to the browser 9if at all).

Comment: Also, note that there is certain "voodoo" required to get perl to handle utf8 well, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/23118.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10824366/23118 is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check below modules. they have hte inforation that you need:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode

https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::QuotedPrint

As You haven't posted what you have tried so far, i am not going a write code from the scratch. However, Check above perl module documentation, they have information.

Comment: Hi slayedbylucifer, thanks for ur response. I have edited my question. Please suggest on it.

Answer (score 1):

If your source code file is encoded as UTF-8 then you need to specify:

```
use utf8;
```

in your source code file to tell the interpreter that you may have strings embedded in your source that are UTF-8.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html

Answer (score 0):

**First**, as PP notes, if your source file is encoded in UTF-8, you should `use utf8;` so that Perl will know that and interpret any string literals in it correctly.

**Second**, make sure the text in the database is also correctly encoded.  The details of this will depend on you database, but e.g. for MySQL, the best way is probably to make sure your text columns have the [`utf8` character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode.html) and the [`utf8_unicode_ci` collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) (or the appropriate national collation scheme, if needed), and to include the [`mysql_enable_utf8` option](http://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql#mysql_enable_utf8) when connecting to the database using DBI.

**Third**, you need to tell Perl that you want your I/O streams to be UTF-8 encoded, too.  You can do this using [`binmode()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html), as in:

```perl
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
```

**Finally**, you also need to tell the browser that you're sending it UTF-8 text.  (I suspect this part is your *actual* problem, but if you do all the other steps too, you'll have achieved a fully Unicode-aware workflow.)  You can do this by sending the HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and/or the equivalent HTML meta tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or, in HTML5, simply:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```